# Android viewpager for screen slides

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to build an app with following requirements:

1. Each page has some image and text, and a right-left page swipe refreshes the page to display new image and text.
2. The user should be able to swipe right-left endlessly (with no limits on number of pages).
3. I want to be able to fetch content for next pages (from a server), prior to user swiping to the next page, for better response times.
4. I want to restrict the user to allow only right-left swipes and no way to swipe back to older pages (only to ensure that I don't need to save older pages in memory). Therefore I can discard older views/pages from memory.

Not sure how I would need to modify the examples given at http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html to achieve the expected results.